# What is the meaning of expression "cherry bomb"?

Tags: meaning, offensive-language

I've heard this word in the song Black Hole from Rob Zombie.
Is it something vulgar or just a regular expression?

Comment: ***Cherry bomb:*** - 
A red, ball-shaped firecracker that explodes with a loud bang. (AHD)

Comment: In the lyrics the meaning probably is the following: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cherry%20bomb

Comment: Please include the context and research you've done. To answer the other question, yes, `cherry bomb` is a RE.

Comment: Other than the literal meaning of a firecracker, the meaning I'm most familiar with is from the [song "Cherry Bomb" by the Runaways](http://www.metrolyrics.com/cherry-bomb-lyrics-the-runaways.html) where it means a young/teenaged "wild" girl. I wouldn't use "cherry bomb" to describe an older woman.

Answer (score 0):

> A number five said he Captain Kirk
>   A number six said "I gotta get to work"
>   A number seven said "Go f**k the prom"
>   A number eight said "Hey, cherry bomb"

There is no way to know what Mr. Zombie actually *means* by "cherry bomb" in this context.  As others have pointed out, the two common meanings are:

1. A small firecracker that makes a loud bang
2. A young, attractive, rebellious woman.

Otherwise, your guess is as good as mine.  I suspect he really wanted to write "f**k the prom", but then he needed to come up with a word that rhymes, and "bomb" was close enough.

Comment: It might be worth noting that poets and songwriters often employ ambiguity and layers of meaning *intentionally*.  Zombie might have written this so that either of the obvious but contradictory meanings makes sense, depending on things like the listener's mood at that moment.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan Sure, but *every* language does this, which is why ELL has rules against answering questions about phrases that require literary interpretation.  Unless there is a reference unique to the English-speaking world, once learners understand the *meaning* of the metaphor, they can usually interpret on their own.